# Can tidesdk be used with the Web Audio API?

Tags: tidesdk

If I build a web app that uses the web audio api can tidesdk be used to package it up and turn it into a desktop app and still have "Web Audio API" functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebKit is currently being upgraded. Once it is, there will be no issue to do exactly what you want. We'll announce the availability of this when it is available.